# Quick, basic exponent problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Quick question regarding some exponential rules:

Why is it that $(1-(1-x))^n = x^n$?

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with exponential rules!

Answer (score 10):

Simply because 
$$
1-(1-x)=1-1-(-x)=x.
$$
This has nothing to do with exponential rules.

Comment: Right... Now I feel dumb :p
Thanks though!

Comment: You're welcome, and no need to feel dumb :)